# Counter resets to same non-zero value?

Tags: php, file-io, counter

I wrote this counter, but there is a strange issue under loads of around 100-200 unique hits per hour. The count resets to a strange value of about "120500" and continues counting from there until later resetting to that same value. Now, a zero value I would understand, but where does the 120500 come from? Here's the full counter code:

```
<?php

    class Counter {
        public $currentCount;
        private $countFile;

        public function __construct($file) {
            if(!file_exists($file)) {
                $fp = fopen($file, 'w');
                fwrite($fp, '1');
                fclose($fp);
            }
            $this->countFile = $file;
            $this->currentCount = file_get_contents($this->countFile);
        }

        public function incrementPerSession() {
            if(isset($_SESSION['visitWritten'])) {
                echo $this->currentCount;
            } else {
                $count = $this->currentCount + 1;
                $this->writeNewCount($count);
                echo $count;
            }
        }

        private function writeNewCount($count) {
            $delay = rand(10000, 80000);
            $fp = fopen($this->countFile, 'w');
            if(flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {   // PHP locks are not reliable.
                usleep($delay);         // usleep() works as a workaround and prevents resets to zero
                fwrite($fp, $count);
                flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
                $_SESSION['visitWritten'] = true;
            } else {
                echo 'Counter: Could not write to file';
            }
            fclose($fp);
        }
    }
?>
```

This only happens occasionally, which I believe is related to simultaneous writes. The session variable "visitWritten" is not used anywhere else on the site. How can I improve this class?

Comment: Your $currentCount is public.

Comment: With that change, it still resets to the same value... I guess I'll fix it with the old way of using a backup file and comparing the values.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea where the ~120500 number is coming from. I'm just going to tackle the race condition here.

A few things to note:

- File locking in linux is *advisory<sup>*</sup>* — everything has to play nice in order to get along, and playing nice is an opt-in thing rather than opt-out.
- `file_get_contents()` doesn't play nice. If the file is locked, oh well — it's getting read anyway. The function doesn't even know a lock is there.
- `fopen($file, w)` truncates the file immediately, before you get a lock on it.

<sub><sup>*</sup>It can be made mandatory with a filesystem mount option, but I've never seen that in use.</sub>

So what to do. Let's start with writing. The idea will be to delay truncating the file until after we've got it locked.

#### Write:

```
$fh = fopen($file, a+); // Open the file in append-or-create mode.
                        // You may as well use the same function for
                        // creating the file as you do to update it.

if (flock($fh, LOCK_EX)) {
    rewind($fh);        // Set the file pointer to the start of the file.

    ftruncate($fh, 0);  // Truncate the file. This is safe since we've got a lock.
                        // Or will be safe, once we make everything respect locks.

    fwrite($fh, $string);
    flock($fh, LOCK_UN);
}
fclose($fh);
```

Now even if something reads the file between the time we open it and get a lock on it they'll get the data as we haven't truncated it yet. All we gotta do is get file reading to respect the lock and all should be safe.

#### Read:

```
$fh = fopen($file, 'r');
if (flock($fh, LOCK_SH)) { // Play nice. Get a shared lock. This will block
                           // if another process has an exclusive lock.
    $string = fread($fh, filesize($file));
    flock($fh, LOCK_UN);
}
fclose($fh);
```

Aside from some error handling that should about do it.

Except there is still a race condition.

If two processes are performing the "read -> increment -> write" cycle at the same time there is a chance they'll both read the same data, then write identical data. It's not as bad as a counter reset, but it is a missed hit. To deal with this you'll want to wrap that entire cycle in a single exclusive lock. So basically you'll end up using it all with something like:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['visitWritten'])) {
    echo read($this->countFile);
} else {
    echo readAndIncrementAndUpdate($this->countFile);
}
```